# El formulario muestra los errores en la vista correcta, ademas inserta de igual forma

Tags: php

Este formulario se redireciona a uncontrorlador que valida cada campo a traves de un preg_match_all

```
<h3>Registro de personal</h3>
            <div>
                <form  action="../Controladores/validacionregistropersonas.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-search ">
                    <div>
                        <label for="rut-persona" >Rut</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rut-persona"   placeholder="Ingrese rut"required >
                    </div>    
                    <div>
                        <label for="Nombre-persona" class="form-label">Nombres</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nombre-persona"   placeholder="Ingrese los nombres" required >
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="Apellido-paterno" class="form-label">Apellido Paterno</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese el apellido paterno"   required >
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="Apellido-materno" >Apellido materno</label>
                        <input type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese el apellido materno"   required>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <label for="Direccion-persona" >Direccion</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la direccion"   name="Direccion-persona" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="Contacto-persona" Contacto</label>
                         <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">+56</span>
                             <input type="text" placeholder="Contacto de la persona" name="Contacto-persona" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <label class="form-label">Correo</label>
                        <input type="email"  placeholder="Ingrese la Correo"  name="Correo-persona" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <div>
                    <label for="Genero-persona" class="form-label">Genero</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="Genero-persona"> 
                        <option selected>Seleccione un genero</option>
                        <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
                        <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                    </select>
                    <div>
                    <label for="AFP-persona" class="form-label">AFP</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="AFP-persona">
                        <option selected>Seleccione afp</option>
                        <option value="Capital">Capital</option>
                        <option value="Cuprum">Cuprum</option>
                        <option value="Habitad">Habitad</option>
                        <option value="Modelo">Modelo</option>
                        <option value="Planvital">Planvital</option>
                        <option value="Provida">Provida</option>
                        <option value="Uno">Uno</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for="Cargo-persona" class="form-label">Cargo</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="cargo-persona"> 
                        <option selected>Cargo del individuo</option>
                        <option value="Capataz">Capataz</option>
                        <option value="Obrero">Obrero</option>
                        <option value="RRHH">RRHH</option>
                        <option value="Jefe de obra">Jefe de obra</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for="Cargo-persona" class="form-label">Prevision</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="prevision-persona"> 
                        <option selected>Prevision</option>
                        <option value="Fonasa">Fonasa</option>
                        <option value="Isapre">Isapre</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
    
                    <div >
                        <label for="Fecha-persona" class="form-label">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                           <input type="date" name="calendario" requiered >
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="Documentos-prevision">Documento prevision</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="file" name="archivo-prevision"  class="form-control" id="Documentos-prevision" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="Documentos-afp">Documento afp</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="file" name="archivo-afp" class="form-control" id="Documentos-afp" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload">
                        </div>
           
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="Documentos-curriculum">Curriculum Vitae</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="file" name="archivo-curriculum"  class="form-control" id="Documentos-curriculum" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="Documentos-examen">Examenes</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="file" name="archivo-examen"  class="form-control" id="Documentos-examen" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="Documentos-examen">Contrato</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
     <input type="file" name="archivo-contrato" class="form-control" id="Documentos-examen" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Registrar">Registrar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Vista del formulario con los datos. introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se muestran campos como el nombre,apellido materno y paterno con caracteres que no pueden tener. Como los numeros y el signo "%" Al darle al boton del registro para enviar esta informacion al controlador muestra los siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Efectivamente muestra que hay un error en el dato de nombre y ademas no esta en el formulario adecuado. No presenta ningun diseño.

Al corregir esta informacion en el formulario y llenar todos los campos de manera correcta a excepcion de los archivos esta se inserta de igual manera en la tabla. Imagen de los campos.

Se observa que los datos estan bien digitados, pero no se sube ningun archivos a los input por lo tanto no deberia poder insertar la informacion ya que se encuentra incompleta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al no subir ningún archivo al formulario se envía la información hacia el controlador y se muestra el error que falta subir un archivo al campo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De igual manera hace la inserción en la base de datos introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Adjunto codigo del controlador

```
if(isset($_POST["Registrar"])){
    $rut=$_POST["rut-persona"];
    $nombre=$_POST["Nombre-persona"];
    $cargopersona=$_POST["cargo-persona"];
    $apellidopaterno=$_POST["Apellido-paterno"];
    $apellidomaterno=$_POST["Apellido-materno"];
    $direccion=$_POST["Direccion-persona"];
    $contacto=$_POST["Contacto-persona"];
    $prevision=$_POST["prevision-persona"];
    $afp=$_POST["AFP-persona"];
    $Correo=$_POST["Correo-persona"];
    $Sexo=$_POST["Genero-persona"];
    $Calendario=$_POST["calendario"];
    $archivoafp=$_FILES["archivo-afp"];
    $archivocurriculum=$_FILES["archivo-curriculum"];
    $archivoexamen=$_FILES["archivo-examen"];
    $archivoprivision=$_FILES["archivo-prevision"];
    $archivocontrato=$_FILES["archivo-contrato"];
    $directorio="../Archivos/".$rut."/";
    $fechanac=$_POST["calendario"];
    
if(!empty($rut) && !empty($nombre) && !empty($apellidopaterno) && !empty($apellidomaterno) && !empty($direccion) && !empty($contacto) ){
    if (validar_letras($nombre)==true){
        
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        El nombre solo se permite letras.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
         
        
    } else if(valida_rut($rut)==true){
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        El rut no es valido.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
       
        
    } else if(validar_letras($apellidomaterno)==true){
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Apellido materno solo permite letras.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
        
    }else if(validar_letras($apellidopaterno)==true){
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Apellido Paterno solo permite letras.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
        
    }else if(validar_numeros($contacto)==true){
        
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Contacto solo permite numeros.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
       
        
    }else if(validar_direccion($direccion)==true){
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        La direccion permite letras, numeros y este simbolo #
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else if(usuarioregistrado($rut)==$rut){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Este rut ya a sido ingresado.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
        
    } else if(validarlargodireccion($direccion)==true){
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Direccion puede tener un minimo de 4 caracteres y maximo 40.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
        
    } else if($afp=="Seleccione afp"){
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Seleccione la afp
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
    }else if($cargopersona=="Cargo del individuo"){
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Seleccione un cargo.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
        
    }else if($Sexo=="Seleccione un genero") {
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Seleccione el genero.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
        
    }else if(validar_correo($Correo)==false){
        ?>   
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Correo no valido
        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <?php
        header("location: ../Vistas/RegistroPersonas.php");
    }else {
        $Rol="0";
        if(insertpersona($nombre,$apellidopaterno,$apellidomaterno,$direccion,$contacto,$prevision,$afp,$cargopersona,$Rol,$fechanac,$rut,$Correo,$Sexo)==true){
            if($_FILES["archivo-afp"] && $_FILES["archivo-curriculum"] && $_FILES["archivo-examen"] && $_FILES["archivo-prevision"] && $_FILES["archivo-contrato"]){

                if(!is_dir($directorio)){
                    mkdir($directorio);
                    
                    $extensionafp=pathinfo($archivoafp["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $extensioncurru=pathinfo($archivocurriculum["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $extensionexamen=pathinfo($archivoexamen["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $extensionprevision=pathinfo($archivoprivision["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $extensioncontrato= pathinfo($archivocontrato["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    if(!$extensionafp =="pdf" || !$extensionafp=="docx"){
                        
                        ?>   
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        El archivo de afp debe ser en formato PDF o Word
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        die();
                    }else if (!$extensioncurru =="pdf" || !$extensioncurru=="docx"){
                        ?>   
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        El archivo de curriculum debe ser en un formato PDF o Word
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        die();
                    }else if(!$extensioncontrato=="pdf" || !$extensioncontrato=="docx"){
                        ?>   
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        El archivo de contrato debe ser en formato PDF o Word
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        die();
                    }else if(!$extensionexamen=="pdf" || !$extensionexamen=="docx"){
                        ?>   
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        El archivo de examen debe ser en formato PDF o Word
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        die();
                    }else if (!$extensionprevision=="pdf" || !$extensionprevision=="docx"){
                        ?>   
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        El archivo de prevision debe ser en formato PDF o Word
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        die();
                    }else{
                        $fapf=$directorio."DOCAFP.".$extensionafp;
                        $fcontra=$directorio."DOCCONTRATO.".$extensioncontrato;
                        $fprevi=$directorio."DOCPREVI.".$extensionprevision;
                        $fexamen=$directorio."DOCEXAMEN.".$extensionexamen;
                        $fcurru=$directorio."DOCCURRU.".$extensioncurru;
                        $nombreafp="DOCAFP.".$extensionafp;
                        $nombrecontrato="DOCCONTRATO.".$extensioncontrato;
                        $nombreprevi="DOCPREVI.".$extensionprevision;
                        $nombreexamen="DOCEXAMEN.".$extensionexamen;
                        $nombrecurru="DOCCURRU.".$extensioncurru;

                        $subirafp=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo-afp"]["tmp_name"], $fapf);
                        $subircurru=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo-curriculum"]["tmp_name"], $fcontra);
                        $subirexamen=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo-examen"]["tmp_name"],  $fprevi);
                        $subirprevi=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo-prevision"]["tmp_name"], $fexamen);
                        $subircontrato=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo-contrato"]["tmp_name"], $fcurru);
                        if($subirafp && $subircurru && $subirexamen && $subirprevi && $subircontrato){

                           if(idpersona($rut)){

                               $resultadopersona= idpersona($rut);
                               insertlink($rut,$fapf,$nombreafp,$resultadopersona);
                               insertlink($rut,$fcontra,$nombrecontrato,$resultadopersona);
                               insertlink($rut,$fprevi,$nombreprevi,$resultadopersona);
                               insertlink($rut,$fexamen,$nombreexamen,$resultadopersona);
                               insertlink($rut,$fcurru,$nombrecurru,$resultadopersona);
                               insertarlogin($rut,$apellidopaterno,$resultadopersona);
  
                               ?>
                               <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                               Registro exitoso.
                               <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                               </div>
                               <?php
                           }else{
                            ?>   
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            Esta persona no existe en los registros. No se puede agregar los archivos.
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            die();
                           }
                        }
                    }
                
                }else{
                    ?>   
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    El directorio ya existe.
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                    
                }else{
                    ?>   
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    Adjunte los archivos son todos los campos obligatorios.
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    die();
                }
        }else{
            ?>   
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            No se pudo agregar.
            <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <?php
            die();
        }
    }


}else if(empty($rut) && !empty($nombre) && empty($apellidopaterno) && empty($apellidomaterno) && empty($direccion) && empty($contacto)){
    ?>   
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    Los campos con asterisco son obligatorios *
    <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <?php

}



}


?>
```

En resumen quiero que todo el formulario al presentar errores y enviar la informacion se muestre cada error en la ventana del registro y que no haga la insercion si faltan campos.

Comment: Lo mejor es que intentes usar html5 pattern https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp Revisa esta documentacion te ahorraras muchisimo tiempo. Saludos